# How to name package of my own project?

Tags: java

The common [naming convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) is:

```
[com/org/...].[companyName/organizationName/....].[projectName]
```

I used to give whatever package name I like for my own projects. Does any naming convention exists for personal project?

Comment: If you aren't publishing the code or software, the conventions are whatever you decide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose any naming convention you like for your personal, private projects.

However I would suggest sticking to the standard Java naming conventions as much as you can:

- It will help avoid namespace collisions if you ever publish your code in the future
- It's always good to follow standard practices (if only to maintain good habits!)

Comment: So what package name prefix you prefer to use for your own projects?

Comment: If you own a Domain, use that. If not, just use a placeholder. HOWEVER: If you ever publish your code, refactor to use a domain you own.

Answer (score 2):

The convention is not so much to use the name of a company or other organization, but to use a **domain name**. Domains are often named after companies, but many developers have their own private domain names which they use to name Java packages in personal projects. Thus, the same convention may be applied for all packages, personal or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

No, This is the standard one. 
This is because, any existant domain will always be unique. Which guarantees the uniqueness of the Package name as well.

So I would suggest to rely on existant domain for package is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you don't publish your software, any collisions are of no concern to anyone but yourself.  If you have a personal domain name, I recommend that you use that. Otherwise make up something that you think is unlikely to collide.

When you do decide to publish your software, it would be a good idea to either get a domain name for your project, or us a real or fictitious one based on (say) the DNS name of the place that you publish your source code; e.g. "net.sourceforge.myproject" ... where "myproject" is your official sourceforge project name.